# Google Maps Search Strategy

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've got a kml file containing coodinates and placemark names and descriptions.  I would like to be able to search this location data (placemark name and description) and result in pinpoints on the map.

I figure I can either keep the data in the kml file or import it into a database.  I am fairly new to the Google Maps API and was wondering if you guys could point me in the right direction to tackle this project.  I am specifically wondering if the data should stay in the KML file (or be placed in a database).  Also, is the data searchable through the Google Maps API, or should a third-party add-in be used?  Thanks!

Environment: Google Maps API v3, ASP.NET 4.0, MSSQL 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to import the data into a [FusionTable](http://support.google.com/fusiontables) (you only have to upload the KML-file, that's all).

Benefits: You may display the geometry(e.g. PlaceMarks) by using a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables), which will be created on serverside automatically and may be filtered and styled on demand.

To search within the table you may send a SQL-like query , e.g. via ajax(no special tool needed, and when the map is not set to private access, also no authorization required)

---

When you use the KML as it is(without importing it into a Fusion-Table), the data may also be displayed by a automatically created [Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers), but the Features can not be styled and also not be filtered by API-implemented methods.

There is also no API-implemented method to search for data inside the KML, you must parse the KML on your own to be able to search within.